# Creating global variable with Python, changes value after initialized

Tags: python

I have been trying to write a small python script for the sha1 algorithm. I needed to initialize the global variables of h0 to h4.

After initalize the value of the integers, it changes to a different int for h0 and h3 values, and not h1, h2 or h4. I'm not sure why, as a quick google search shows that h0 and h3 are not special characters.

Relevant code:

```
h0 = 0
h1 = 0
h2 = 0
h3 = 0
h4 = 0

#Initialize some variables
def init_var():
    global h0
    global h1
    global h2
    global h3
    global h4

    h0 = 01100111010001010010001100000001
    h1 = 11101111110011011010101110001001
    h2 = 10011000101110101101110011111110
    h3 = 00010000001100100101010001110110
    h4 = 11000011110100101110000111110000

    print "\n\n\n h0", h0
    print "h1", h1
    print "h2", h2
    print "h3", h3
    print "h4", h4
```

When I print it in the console, it gives:

```
robert@robert-VirtualBox:~/sha1-hash-algorithm$ python testalgorithm.py



 h0 1393027350754575011593322497
h1 11101111110011011010101110001001
h2 10011000101110101101110011111110
h3 19342823492383875910635592
h4 11000011110100101110000111110000
```

Can someone tell me why is this happening? Is this some special character in python?

I have included a screen shot below of the output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python numbers start with `0` are in base 8(octal numbers).

```
>>> 011
9
```

`011` equals `1 * (8**1) + 1 * (8**0)` = 9
`0111` equals `1 * (8**1) + 1 * (8**1) + 1 * (8**0)` = 73

In your case, it works as expected.

```
>>> h0 = 01100111010001010010001100000001
>>> h0
>>> 1393027350754575011593322497L
```

Answer (score 1):

@luoluo has told you the reason. So If you want to assign a binary number to a variable you should use the prefix: 0b

```
>>> a = 0b10010
>>> print(a)
18
>>> a = 0b001010
>>> print(a)
10
```

And you should know that when you print a binary number to the console, Python will show a decimal number automatically.